# realization of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

In [s. Cerrai, Normal deviations from the averaged motion for some reaction–diffusion equations with fast oscillating perturbation] it is given a reaction diffusion PDE with operator $\mathcal{A}$ and some Dirichlet Boundary conditions. Then  it's written as a differential equation in abstract form on some Hilbert space $H$ with operator $A$ which is the realization of $\mathcal{A}$ in $H$ endowed with Dirichlet boundary conditions.

What do we mean with the realization of $\mathcal{A}$ in $H$?